# update single value in mysql is taking to long -> timeout

Tags: mysql

this has been asked several times, but I can't find any solution to my problem.

I have a database with a table called 'DataPoint'. It has 513 rows.

```
mysql> describe DataPoint;
+-----------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| value     | double     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| timestamp | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| sensorID  | char(12)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| parseSync | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * from DataPoint where id=1;
+----+-------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| id | value | timestamp           | sensorID   | parseSync |
+----+-------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | -5.88 | 2015-07-08 22:01:34 | wsuH8FMVwO |         0 |
+----+-------+---------------------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> update DataPoint SET parseSync = 1 where id=1;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

The problem is with the last command 'update DataPoint SET parseSync = 1 where id=1;'. The database won't answer in 50 sec and then throws a timeout.

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50    |
+--------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't see any error in my syntax, but i'm not an expert in mysql... am I missing something trivial?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Any chance there is a trigger on this table?

Comment: There is probably another thread which has a lock on the row. You can use `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` and `information_schema.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS` to find out which one it is.

Comment: Thanks Vatev, I found something in INNODB_TRX. After restarting the service, now it's working.

Comment: @otmezger could you please write your own answer and mark it as accepted , so that if someone gets the same issue , they also can through that answer and fix their things, i hope you will do it and contribute to this amazing community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I came up with a fairly simple solution. I found an entry in `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` as @Vatev mentioned, so I just restarted the service daemon with

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

after that, everything was fine.

thanks

Comment: how can i use it ? i am running in same issue

Answer (score 1):

Its not always your query that causing issue. Sometime its other query holding lock on particular table and went into unreachable state. I'd suggest you to follow below steps to find out Culprit query.

**Step 1:** Execute `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` in MySQL. It'll show query running on table and locked resource.

**Step 2:** Now kill that process. Find out process id of that query using `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and kill that process using `KILL process_id;`

**Step 3:** Find out solution for that Culprit query.

OR

Show us that Culprit query and We'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If like me, you use PHPMyAdmin, then execute this statement:

```sql
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

A table listing all running process will be shown. Look for the process that is locking the table and click the word Kill in the first column to stop the process.

[image]